# Valgrind embedded in gtest

Tags: valgrind, googletest

I'm interested in finding the best approach to incorporate Valgrind into my gtest framework to guarantee the absence of memory leaks and access to invalid addresses. In my testing, I aim to simulate accessing invalid addresses as I'm developing a private memory pool with specific allocation and deallocation functionality. To achieve this, I utilize Valgrind macros, such as the following example:

```
VALGRIND_DISCARD(VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_NOACCESS(address, size));
```

The problems I'm facing and looking for advice are:

1. Valgrind outputs are printed only at the program end (when I am running `valgrind ./my_tests`. I am not allowed to use after-run scripts that analyze the Valgrind output
2. I have many cases where the program aborts and I EXPECT it in my tests. In these cases, I don't want valgrind error at all. I thought to use `--gtest_filter` for that but maybe there is a better solution.
3. I didn't find any GitHub open-source projects that implement the above solution and that made me wonder if there is a different easiest/better approach

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use the following valgrind flags: `--exit-on-first-error=yes --error-exitcode=1`, then I may use regular EXPECT_DEATH, e.g.

```
  EXPECT_DEATH(
      {
        char exam = buff[0]; // <-- try to read from already released buffer
        if (exam == 'Y') {
          FAIL() << "We shouldn't get here, are you running gtest executable "
                    "with valgrind?";
        }
      },
      "");
```